# Angular: Can't use async pipe

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to show a spinner using a observable which resolves to a boolean value using a async pipe in a template. The value of the observable is set in the service. I am not able to figure out whats going wrong. The observable value seems to resolve to undefined. Why this could be not working?

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rngdxn) is the stackblitz created for the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use a `Subject()`, or do the setLoader in `ngAfterViewInit`, at the moment you do `.next(true)` the template is not subscribed to it yet:

Solution 1:

```
export class AppComponent {
   loading$: Observable<boolean>;

   constructor(private myservice: MyService) {
     this.loading$ = myservice.loading$;
   }

   ngAfterViewInit() {
     this.myservice.setLoader(true);
   }
}
```

Solution 2:

```
export class AppComponent {
   loading$: Observable<boolean>;

   constructor(private myservice: MyService) {
     this.loading$ = myservice.loading$.pipe(
       shareReplay(1)
     );
   }

   ngOnInit() {
     this.myservice.setLoader(true);
   }
}
```

Solution 3:

```
private loadingSource = new ReplaySubject(1);

loading$ = this.loadingSource.asObservable();

constructor() { }

setLoader(isLoading: boolean) {
  this.loadingSource.next(isLoading);
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary for an `observable` to subscribe it before value is emitted? If yes, then how come this works - `const obs = Observable.create(observer => {
  observer.next(1)
});

obs.subscribe( data => {
  console.log(data)
})`;
Here subscription is done after the value is emitted and it still works.

Comment: @DevChoudhary it depends on the Observable, a `Subject` is a hot observable, A hot Observable is an Observable that can start emitting events before you subscribe. This means you can miss previous events that have already emitted. In your example you create an Observable with a certain subscriber function. This subscriber function is called when you run `obs.subscribe`, which means you subscribe before the `observer.next(1)` is called

Comment: Okay, that means even if we convert a `subject` to an `observable` using `asObservable()` method, it stills behave like a `subject` in a hot way. So previous events emitted are lost. The `asObservable()` method for `subject` does not make it cold or lazy `observable`, right?

Comment: @DevChoudhary exactly, but if you add a pipe to it with a shareReplay(1) operator, you get what you want. But you basically made a ReplaySubject, so you might as well use that

Answer (score 1):

It is undefined because we run `setLoader` inside `ngOnInit` where view is not ready. At that time, `loading$` in service class is still undefined. When template renders it, definitely it is undefined.

I'd move the `setLoader` to `ngAfterViewInit`

```
import { Component, VERSION, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core'; // import AfterViewInit
import { MyService } from './my.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit { // add AfterViewInit
 constructor(public myservice: MyService) {
 }

 ngOnInit() {

 }

 ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.myservice.setLoader(true); // move it here
 }
}
```

Also I checked that there's a typo in the template, the original code uses `myservice.loader$` but it is supposed to be `myservice.loading$`.

```html
<div *ngIf="myservice.loading$ | async">
  Loading
</div>
```

Hope it helps